# On reports other than on object Case, i am unable to get created date and time in the report. Is this expected? Are there any workarounds?

Tags: reporting, datetime

On reports other than on object Case, i am unable to get created date and time in the report.  Is this expected? Are there any workarounds?

Or am i missing something.  I am sure that createddate always capture the date/time in the database.  Why not show it in the report?

For case: [image: Case Report]

For Other objects:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding the fields to the report using the Report Builder? You should be able to see CreatedDate on all objects, unless Field Level Security is preventing visibility.

Comment: Sorry i think i didn't frame the question right.  The problem is that i can only see the created date and not time in the report.  On the case object both can be seen when you pull in date/time opened or last modified date.  Added screenshots to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing something. A workaround is to create a new custom field of type Date/Time, and then a workflow rule to update it with "NOW()" each time a record is created.

This won't work retroactively, unfortunately, but you could do a one-time export/import to populate this new field with the past Created Date + a time of midnight.

Comment: `CreatedDate` will hold correct values when queried for so an Apex datafix should work OK without "midnight everywhere". It's just that in reports the granularity is cut down to days for whatever reason...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a formula field on the object of return type Date/Time. Set the value of the formula field as the CreatedDate of that object and save.

Now you can include this field on to your reports to see the time portion as well.

The benefit of this approach is that it will work for all records (i.e both new and old) without any additional effort.